# How to disable the "Windows Media Player cannot download media information..." pop-up after ripping a CD?

Tags: windows-10, windows-media-player

I kind of like ripping my audiobook CDs to MP3 using Windows Media Player because it's free, easy, and comes with Windows. I really like how, when a CD is done being ripped, it can (in theory) auto-eject the CD so I can quickly put in the next audiobook CD. However, this auto-eject never works because of this annoying error:

[image]

I have tried all the steps in [this article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/how-to-disable-the-windows-media-player-cannot/17b00dda-774c-4d03-acfc-158c86632ea4) (titled **How to disable the "Windows Media Player cannot download media information..." pop-up after ripping a CD without enabling network connectivity**.) and it doesn't work. And I have tried this on other PCs as well.

So then I click OK and it finally ejects. This is so annoying to have to do EVERY TIME. I have read several tips/guides on how to avoid this but none of them work, including the link mentioned at the top of this post. There must be a registry tweak or something to prevent this from happening. I have unchecked everything in the `Privacy` and `Network` tabs, plus I tried the reg hacks mentioned in the link.

I'm using Windows 10. Version doesn't matter, this happens on every Win10 version.

Comment: You might try a free third-party tool, such as open-source fre:ac . See https://alternativeto.net/software/express-rip/ for other alternatives.

Comment: DrMoishe, I'm liking fre:ac, but how can I make it auto-rip when a CD is inserted, and auto-eject upon completion? These are 2 great features in WMP.

Comment: Not sure if it's fully impolemented, but see https://www.freac.org/latest-news-mainmenu-2/14?start=12

Comment: Yeah, found both checkboxes, but auto-rip doesn't work. Only auto-eject works. I'm going back to WMP and using an auto-button clicker to click that annoying popup for me.